# how to pipe ffmpeg to ffmpeg?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

How to pipe ffmpeg output frame by frame to ffmpeg? i dont see any library either nodejs or python that as powerfull as the application directly. so what i need to do is take rawvideo from ffmpeg, then manipulate in middle stage, then push again that buffer to ffmpeg. i got inavlid buffer size after encode 24 frames. is stdin buffer push too fast?

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const path = require('path');

const decArgs = [
    '-i', path.join(__dirname + '/public/blackpink.mp4'),
    '-c:v', 'copy',
    '-an',
    '-f', 'rawvideo',
    '-'
];

const decode = spawn('ffmpeg', decArgs);

const encArgs = [
    '-f', 'rawvideo',
    '-video_size', '854x480',
    '-i', '-',
    '-c:v', 'libx264',
    '-preset', 'ultrafast',
    '-crf', '30',
    '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
    '-y',
    path.join(__dirname + '/public/output.mp4')
];

const encode = spawn('ffmpeg', encArgs, {
    stdio: [
        decode.stdout,
        null,
        null
    ]
})

encode.stderr.on('data', data => {
    console.log(data.toString())
})
```